# How to get the number of new subscriptions and the number of subscription renewals in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Having this table representing users subscriptions:

```
CREATE TABLE `subscriptions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL
);
```

There can be multiple records with the same email.

How can I get the number of new subscriptions per month and the number of subscription renewals per month?

Let's say a subscription was made with email "aaa@a.com" in July 2018. If another subscription is made in August 2018 with "aaa@a.com", it's a renewal. All subscriptions that was made in August 2018 where the email is not registered in July 2018 are new subscriptions.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What is a "new subscription"?  What is a "subscription renewal"?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by determining the first time a subscriber is seen:

```
select year(created_at), month(created_at),
       count(*) as num_subscribers,
       sum( min_ca = created_at ) as num_new_subscribers,
       sum( min_ca > created_at ) as num_renewals
from subscriptions s join
     (select email, min(created_at) as min_ca
      from subscriptions s
      group by email
     ) ss
     on s.email = ss.email
group by  year(created_at), month(created_at);
```

Comment: I get always 0 in num_renewals.

Answer (score 0):

By counting only the renewals and subtracting from the total number of subscriptions you can get also the new subscriptions:

```
select t.cyear, t.cmonth, (t.total - t.renewals) newsubs, t.renewals
  from (
  select 
    year(s.created_at) cyear, month(s.created_at) cmonth, 
    count(*) total,
    sum(
      case when exists (
        select 1 from subscriptions
        where 
          email = s.email and 
          last_day(s.created_at - interval 1 month) = last_day(created_at))
        then 1
        else 0
      end
    ) renewals
  from subscriptions s
  group by year(s.created_at), month(s.created_at)
) t
```

Comment: I get an error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'

Comment: There are 3 parameters in datediff. Did you copy the code exactly as it is above?

Comment: Yes, I am using MySQL

Comment: Now I get an error syntax near 'then 1
        else 0
      end'

Comment: Thanks it works now. I have a question. Does it take into account iterative mode?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Does the renewals count of a given month takes into account all previous months, not only the first month where a subscription was made?

Comment: A subscription is considered as a renewal, as you mention in your question, only if there exists a subscription in the previous month.

Comment: Let's say the very first subscription was made in January 2018. If a susbcription with email "aaa@aa.com" was made in January 2018 and in March 2018, it counts as a renewal in March 2018. If a subscription with "bbb@bb.com" was first made in February 2018 and also in July 2018, it counts as a renewal in July 2018. Does it take it into account?

Comment: I analysed your code with some data and the results are far from those expected.

Comment: Maybe because your question has nothing to do with what you really want. Read again what you say in the question:*Let's say a subscription was made with email "aaa@a.com" in July 2018. If another subscription is made in August 2018 with "aaa@a.com", it's a renewal. All subscriptions that was made in August 2018 where the email is not registered in July 2018 are new subscriptions* and what you say in your last comment.